# Why is this throwing a TypeError?

Tags: reactjs, typeerror

I have a react component that is supposed to map a 'persons' state and return a 'person' list, it displays the list fine, and deletePersonHandler still works, but when I begin typing in an input it throws a TypeError.

TypeError: props.persons.map is not a function

I'm quite new to JS and very new to React so any pointers would be much appreciated!

My persons component:

```
const persons = (props) =>  
  props.persons.map((person, index) => {
        return (
          <Person 
          click={() => props.clicked(index)}
          name={person.name}
          age={person.age}
          //each item in a list needs a key, should be unique and unchanging
          key={person.id}
          changed={(event) => props.changed(event, person.id)} />
          )
      });
```

Then in App.js I have

```
let people = null;

    if (this.state.showPersons) {
      people = (
        <div>
          <Persons 
            persons = {this.state.persons}
            clicked = {this.deletePersonHandler}
            changed = {this.nameChangedHandler} 
            />     
        </div>
      );       
    }
```

And finally I have my nameChangedHandler also in App.js

```
nameChangedHandler = (event, id) => {
        const personIndex = this.state.persons.find(p => {
      return p.id === id;
    });
    const person = {...this.state.persons[personIndex]};
    person.name = event.target.value;
    person[personIndex] = person; 
    this.setState({ persons: person });
  }
```

I'm expecting the name to change as you type, however as soon as you start typing the typeerror is thrown

Many thanks!

Comment: `person` in App.js is an object, and you're calling `setState` and setting `persons` to that object.  `persons` is now an object, not an array, and you can't call `.map` on an object.

Answer (score 0):

It is because persons is an object. and .map is a function unique to Arrays
instead of `props.persons.map` try something like `Object.keys(props.persons).map`

doc for `Object.keys()` is here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Hope that helped (:

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `persons` to an object. From the code, I can only conclude that `persons` is an array initially (since you're able to call `find` on it). You can change your `nameChangeHandler` to

```
nameChangedHandler = (event, id) => {
  const personIndex = this.state.persons.find(p => {
    return p.id === id;
  });
  const person = { ...this.state.persons[personIndex] };
  person.name = event.target.value;
  person[personIndex] = person;
  // Notice the change here
  const newPersons = [...this.state.persons].splice(personIndex, 1, person);
  this.setState({ persons: newPersons });
};
```

I use [Array#splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to replace the old `person` and generate a new array.